# restore-sqldatabase report status during restore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there any way to get the Restore_Database command to report status during execution? My database is small and I'd like to record output to a text file. I think I saw a green status bar that is not what I'm looking for. Is there no switch on the cmdlet or way to track the status on the powershell side?

```
Restore-SqlDatabase  -ServerInstance "MyServer" -Database "TestDB" -ReplaceDatabase -BackupFile "C:\Temp\W007808\TestDB\MyServer_TestDB_20161009_013101.bak"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following query to monitor sql restore and backup operations

```
SELECT percent_complete, *
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
WHERE command In ( 'RESTORE DATABASE', 'BACKUP DATABASE' )
```

More details can be found on [this page](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2343/how-to-monitor-backup-and-restore-progress-in-sql-server/)

Comment: That is interesting. I'm looking for something on the power-shell side built into the command. If I read into your response, I'm guessing the restore-sqldatabase command provides no functionality for status.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one we use:

```
SELECT r.session_id,r.command,CONVERT(NUMERIC(6,2),r.percent_complete)
AS [Percent Complete],CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DATEADD(ms,r.estimated_completion_time,GetDate()),20) AS [ETA Completion Time],
CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),r.total_elapsed_time/1000.0/60.0) AS [Elapsed Min],
CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),r.estimated_completion_time/1000.0/60.0) AS [ETA Min],
CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),r.estimated_completion_time/1000.0/60.0/60.0) AS [ETA Hours],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000),(SELECT SUBSTRING(text,r.statement_start_offset/2,
CASE WHEN r.statement_end_offset = -1 THEN 1000 ELSE (r.statement_end_offset-r.statement_start_offset)/2 END)
FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)))
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r WHERE command IN ('RESTORE DATABASE','BACKUP DATABASE')
```

I just saw your comment about wanting it in powershell.
[Here is a Blog Post on how to do it](https://rhartskeerl.wordpress.com/tag/powershell-2/)